# Dirty Shutdown - Repair or Reseed?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have a 3 node Exchange 2010 DAG (2 servers in production, 1 in DR). Each mailbox database has 3 copies (2 in production, 1 in DR). Backup Exec takes a backup from the passive copy in production however this has failed due to dirty shutdown. We cannot take a backup from DR at the moment, so my question is can I just reseed the passive copy in production or should I attempt to repair the database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean "repair" as in using ESEUTIL, don't do that with a DAG-replicated database.  It changes the signature and you'll wreak havoc on it.

Assuming that the database doesn't remount and resume sync automatically, then just reseed it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to reseed the passive copy. Don't run repairs on DB that are in production.

If your active database copy is not in dirty shutdown state, then you just need to reseed it.

**Here are the steps:**

--First get the status of the copy using the PowerShell cmdlet -

**Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus**

--Now repair the database by suspending the copy between the active and passive database using following command -

**Suspend-MailboxDatabaseCopy –Identity "DB01\EX01"**

--You need to re-seed the database, first clear off any copies of the database. then use below command -

**Update-MailboxDatabaseCopy -Identity "DB01\EX01" -DeleteExistingFiles**

This will reseed the database from active copy to passive copy.
For more information about [reseeding Exchange database, refer this link](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/reseed-a-failed-database-copy-in-exchange-server.php).